# A question on eigenfunctions of Laplacian.

Tags: real-analysis, ordinary-differential-equations, laplacian, p-laplacian

Given two functions $f,g:(0,1)\to\mathbb{R}$ such that $f''+\lambda f = 0$ and $g''+\gamma g = 0$, $f(0) = f(1)$ and $g(0) = g(1)$.$\lambda,\gamma \ge 2\pi$

Show that (with minimal fuss any) $$\lvert|f+g|\rvert_{L^2}^2 = \lvert|f|\rvert_{L^2}^2 + \lvert|g|\rvert_{L^2}^2$$

Appreciate if you don't do any integration or use of any trigonometry.

Comment: I don't see how you can discuss $\Vert \cdot \Vert_{L^2}$ without *some* reference to integration . . .

Comment: @RobertLewis : I mean avoiding any integration based on fomulae or integration of closed form expressions.

Comment: Look up "Sturm-Liouville self-adjoint", you should find something rather general. (It is a bit odd because you selected the eigenvalues rather than selecting the boundary conditions, which makes it not obvious how to use general considerations about self-adjoint operators.)

Comment: Yeah, I think something about boundary conditions might be needed . .

Comment: @Ian updated. I think they make sense.

Comment: Then yes, in this case you have a self-adjoint Sturm-Liouville eigenvalue problem and general theory applies to give the orthogonality required.

Comment: @Ian : Is there any S-L like theory for functions in higher dimensional Euclidean spaces.

Comment: Are you sure you don't want $\Vert f + g \Vert_{L^2}^2 = \Vert f \Vert_{L^2}^2 + \Vert g \Vert_{L^2}^2$?  I'm pretty sure your conjectured conclusion is false as stated.

Comment: @RobertLewis Ah forgot about squareroot. Need to square. Thanks for pointing out.

Comment: I'm trying to solve this with "minimal fuss" but the shifting conditions in the question create more stuff to fuss over!

Comment: OK, don't mean to be obnoxious.  But you also need to consider saying something about $\lambda$ and $\gamma$, I'll warrant.  Why did you take that stuff out?  Just trying to help.  No offense meant.  Cheers!

Comment: I added the tag, "differential equations".